# Results printed from the database are not what is quite expected

Tags: php

```
 require 'db/connect.php';
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT last_name +' '+ first_name as full_name, bio FROM people")) {
    if ($count = $result->num_rows) {
        echo '<p>', $count , '</p>';

        // while ($rows = $result->fetch_object()) {
            // print_r($rows);
            // echo '<br/>';
        // }

        while ($rows = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo $rows->full_name, ' ' , $rows->bio, '<br />';
        }

        $result->free();
    }
} else {
    die($db->error);
}
```

The database table people contains two rows of data where the columns are id, first_name, last_name, bio and created.

> row 1: id=1, first_name=kelly, last_name='wafukho', bio=computer scientist.
>   row 2: id=2, first_name=gonzaga, last_name='situma', bio=graphic designer.

When the query below is run it gives me 0 computer scientist for row 1 and 0 graphic designer for row 2. What could be the reason for this? is the problem with my sql syntax or the php handles objects?
Am using the mysql database.

Comment: It looks like you can't use the `+` operator for string concatenation - your database is trying to add the names as numbers and coming up with zero. Some databases allow that, some don't, so you'll need to indicate what database you're using.

Comment: you are fetching object so you have to select one row set limit 1 in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `CONCAT` function to join fields

```
SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) as full_name, bio FROM people
```

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching object so you have to select one row set limit 1 in query.

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT last_name +' '+ first_name as full_name, bio FROM people limit 1")) {
```

or fetch array for multiple rows.